# App2sd compatible email app

Tags: email, app2sd, 2.3.3-gingerbread

I have a Casio G'zOne Commando C771 phone. It only has 400 MB of internal storage (!!!). I want to connect to my email, but if I use the built in email app, it will very quickly fill up what little storage I have left.

In most cases, I have to use "App2SD" apps and never use the built in apps that come with the phone (outdated, and if I even download the updates they will immediately take up that little bit of space - so I only updated the Play Store and nothing else). I have tried downloading other email apps but have been unsuccessful. None of the ones I have tried have the "Move to SD" button enabled. Alternately, if an app is minimal in size (< 10 MB) and allows me to store the emails on the SD card, that would also be acceptable.

Here are email apps I have tried so far: GMail (maybe it would work, but since it comes as a system App I can't move to SD), myMail, Aqua Mail, and "Mails" (by Apyfie).

I have a Roundcube server, so I have also tried the Roundcube app, which IS surprisingly app2SD compatible - unfortunately it's broken in almost all other aspects - for instance, I can only see my last 5 emails and no others - so I still can't use it.

I also tried to locate "K-9 mail" but it says it's not compatible with this version of Android.

This phone has Android version 2.3.3.

I am aware that I could probably root the phone and do it that way, but I would prefer not to.